# React - updating an object array in the state with setState

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, setstate

I'm working on a table planner app where guests can be assigned to dinner tables.
I have created an object array in the state called tabledata, which will contain objects like so:

```js
    this.state = {
      tabledata: [
        {
          name: "Top Table",
          guests: ["guest1", "guest2", "guest3"]
        },
        {
          name: "Table One",
          guests: ["guest3", "guest4", "guest5"]
        }
      ]
    }
```

I am then creating a drag and drop interface where guests can move between tables. I have attempted to update the state like so:

```js
  updateTableList (tablename, guest) {
    const selectedTableObj = this.state.tabledata.filter((tableObj) => tableObj.name === tablename);
    const otherTableObjs = this.state.tabledata.filter((tableObj) => tableObj.name !== tablename);

    selectedTableObj[0].guests.push(guest);
    const updatedObjectArray = [...otherTableObjs, selectedTableObj];

    this.setState({
      tabledata: [...otherTableObjs, ...selectedTableObj]
    });

  }
```

This works but because I am removing selectedTableObj from the state and then adding it to the end of the array I'm getting some funky results on screen. The updated table always goes to the bottom of the page (as you'd expect).

**How can I update the object without changing its position within the array?**

Answer (score 1):

Find the index of the table you want to update using [`Array.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). Create a new `tabledata` array. Use [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the items before and after the updated table, and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) them into the new `tabledata` array. Create a new table object using object spread, add the updated `guests` array, and add the table object between the previous items:

Code (not tested):

```
updateTableList(tablename, guest) {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    const tableData = prevState.tabledata;
    const selectedTableIndex = tableData.findIndex((tableObj) => tableObj.name === tablename);
    const updatedTable = tableData[selectedTableIndex];

    return {
      tabledata: [
        ...prevState.tabledata.slice(0, selectedTableIndex),
        {
          ...updatedTable,
          guests: [...updatedTable.guests, guest]
        },
        ...prevState.tabledata.slice(selectedTableIndex + 1)
      ]
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: I think I like this answer best. Seeing this code reminds me I saw Wes Bos update the state like this on a course I did. I should have remembered really. FYI - I tested your code and there were a couple of typos in there. tabledata.findIndex should be tableData.findIndex and the same for tabledata[selectedTableIndex]. Could you update your answer with these coz it really might help someone else as I suspect this is common issue in React for relative newbies. Thanks appreciate the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

`selectedTableObj[0].guests.push(guest)` directly mutates the state which is not encouraged in React.

Try this:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  const newData = [...prevState.tabledata];
  // if you pass in `index` as argument instead of `tablename` then this will not be needed
  const index = prevState.tabledata.findIndex(table => tableObj.name === tablename); 

  newData[index] = {
    ...newData[index],
    guests: newData[index].guests.concat([guest]),
  };
  return { tabledata: newData };
});
```

You also did not remove the guest from its previous table so you need to modify for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a Array.reduce

```
let newState = this.state
// let newState = {...this.state} // in case you want everything immutable
newState.tableData = newState.tableData.reduce((acc, table) => 
  if(table.name === tableName) {
    return acc.concat({...table, guests: table.guests.concat(newGuest)})
  } else {
    return acc.concat(table)
  }
)
```